# Why is this GET request to a Rails API not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, get, typeahead.js

I'm using the following code to `GET` all the Airport data (`localhost:3000/api/v1/airports`) so [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) can autocomplete the airport information.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

    var airports = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('search_string'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: {
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/v1/airports"
        }
    });

    // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
    airports.initialize();

    // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
    // options being used
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'airports',
        displayKey: 'search_string',
        // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
        // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
        source: airports.ttAdapter()
    });

});
```

When I deploy this to Heroku and visit the form page the console in Chrome returns the following:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/airports.json net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE application-b3c93a17005e4f5b078b985c7fa12088.js:3
```

It should respond to the following controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AirportsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
      respond_to :json

      def index
        respond_with(Airport.all)
      end

      def search
        respond_with(Airport.pluck(:search_string))
      end

      def show
        respond_with(Airport.find(params[:id]))
      end

      def create
        @airport = Airport.new(airport.params)
        if @airport.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @airport }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        @airport = Airport.find(params[:id])
        if @airport.update(todo_params)
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @airport }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        respond_with Airport.destroy(params[:id])
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This is what the route looks like:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    get 'airports/search',   to: 'airports#search', as: 'search'

    resources :airports, :airlines, :countries
  end
end
```

**It does work in my development environment. Any ideas?**

Comment: Show us the controller you expect to respond, and the route that should match.

Comment: localhost on Heroku???? I don't think so...

Comment: @TamerShlash I've updated the question with the info. The code is working when I run it locally.

Comment: @RubyRacer Simple copy paste.

Comment: `localhost:3000` should NOT be there. There should be the corresponding hostname of your Heroku deployment.... Have you hardcoded `localhost` anywhere in your code? Maybe clear your browser cache?

Comment: @RubyRacer No I haven't, that's why Im confused about the reason this is happening.

Comment: Very curious... Maybe this is trivial, but have you flushed your browser cache?

Comment: @RubyRacer Doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56299/discussion-between-ruby-racer-and-narzero).

Comment: @RubyRacer Precompiling the assets solved it. Post the answer to the question so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assets, specifically your javascript, contained hardcoded link to `http://localhost:3000` for a GET/json request, I guess from some test in your javascript code.

It got compiled and remained there.

When in production environment, the changes you make to your assets do not apply to the compiled assets (they are compiled...).

Assets get compiled with the only purpose to load faster....

So, after each change you must re-compile the assets for changes to take effect. It is a tedious process (I repeat, only in standard production environment), but it is necessary if you are running on production an application still under development (it's happening more often than you may imagine).

This is the reason why recompiling your assets and restarting your application server will solve your problem.